# click event for dynamic button inside a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling, datalist

I have a DataList and bind it corrertly.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str_cmd, conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dtlst_periodicTask.DataSource = ds;
dtlst_periodicTask.DataBind();
pds.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
pds.AllowPaging = true;
pds.PageSize = 25;
pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
lnkbtnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
lnkbtnPrevious.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
```

and some codes for paging.
After that, I need to add a number of Buttons in each row **dynamically** because the number of buttons is not fix.

```
foreach (DataListItem item in dtlst.Items)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);  

    pnl_users.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

But the button click event does not work.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code does not fire.
}
```

When I put a Button in .aspx page, have access and it works.

```
protected void dtlst object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: you must provide the code behind page because its matter where you make that calls

Answer (score 0):

but why are you attempting to inject a button?

Why not just include the button in the markup in the first place? I can't really see the need or reason to layout a datalist, and THEN decide to use code?

Just drag + drop in a button into the datalist, and you are quite much done.

So here is our datalist - we dropped in a plane jane button.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="border-style:solid;color:black;width:300px;margin-left:25px">

      <div id="mybox" runat="server" style="padding:5px;text-align:right">

            <p>Hotel Name: <asp:TextBox ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></p>
            <p>First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="FirstName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></p>
            <p>Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("LastName") %>'    /></p>
            <p>City: <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("City") %>'  /></p>
            <p>Province: <asp:TextBox ID="Province" runat="server" Text ='<%# Eval("Province") %>'  /></p>
            Active: <asp:CheckBox ID="Active" runat="server" Checked = '<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdRow" runat="server" Text="Row click This item" 
            />

        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:15px"></div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

And our code to fill looks like this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            MyLoadData();
    }
    void MyLoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
        string strSQL = "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

Now, lets wire up the button click, like this:

[image]

so, create new event in above (inteli-sense offers this choice).

```
    protected void cmdRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        DataListItem gRow = (DataListItem)btn.Parent;
        Debug.Print("Row index = " + gRow.ItemIndex.ToString());
        int pkID = (int)(DataList1.DataKeys[gRow.ItemIndex]);
        Debug.Print("Data base PK id = " + pkID.ToString());

        Debug.Print("Hotel name = " + ((TextBox)(gRow.FindControl("HotelName"))).Text);
        Debug.Print("City       = " + ((TextBox)(gRow.FindControl("City"))).Text);
        Debug.Print("--------------------");
    }
```

And out output is this:

```
Row index = 1
Data base PK id = 72
Hotel name = Banff Rocky Mountain Resort
City       = Banff
--------------------
```

so, it not at all clear why you want to spend the time, effort, and that of writing code when you can as a general rule just drop in a good old plane jane button from the designer right into the datalist, and then simple wire up a event.

## Edit:

You can lead a horse to water - but can you get the horse to drink the water?

You can as noted inject a button, but I REALLY but REALLY but REALLY do not recommend doing this.

However, to get the button click event to work, then you can do this:

```
            HtmlButton btn = new HtmlButton();
            
            btn.InnerText = "Index " + e.Item.ItemIndex;
            btn.Attributes.Add("onclick","__doPostBack('BtnTest2','')");
            btn.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
            HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("mybox");
            MyDiv.Controls.Add(btn);
```

## Edit2:

Ok, there seems to be a issue of persistence.

So, adding MUST occur on page load (or could be earlier).

And the buttons have to be re-inserted each time on post-backs.

This now works:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            MyLoadData();
        }
        AddBtns();
    }
    void MyLoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
        string strSQL = "SELECT TOP 3 * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            DataList1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

    void AddBtns()
    {
        foreach (DataListItem gRow in DataList1.Items)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Index " + gRow.ItemIndex;
            btn.ID = "Btn" + gRow.ItemIndex;
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(BtnTest3);

            HtmlGenericControl MyDiv = (HtmlGenericControl)gRow.FindControl("mybox");
            MyDiv.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
    }

    void BtnTest3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("buttn3  click");
    }
```

Note two changes:

We don't add/inject the buttons ONLY on !IsPostback.

We inject the buttons each time on page load

We did not use the Item bound event.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer, but I need to add buttons dynamically, because the number of buttons for each row is not fix.

Comment: I'm just making a strong case for avoiding injection of buttons. As a general rule, the resolve of the click event occurs at compile time - not run time.  You can wire up a button with a JavaScript "do post back", but it oh so much easy to approach as per above. I mean, if it just 1-4 buttons, then hide/show them and use the row databound event to set this (again a whole lot less effort).  Also, if you have more then just a few buttons, the the position of them changes - no motor memory for the UI and for users (it becomes hard to get used to what you can click on a row with changes..

Comment: As noted, I stated that I rare approach things this way. You may have well made a case for a rare need/alternative, but if you can say have 1-4 buttons to show/hide, you going to be much better off here, and very little code.  Also, what code stub you plan to have those buttons call - since that for sure is compile time code - you can't inject code for each button - it not possible. So what code behind do you plan to have those buttons run? In other words, those buttons will have to call existing code stub(s) in the code behind regardless - right?

Comment: Thanks again. Could you please find the wrong part of code?

Comment: Well, there going to be a rather long list of issues - you also note that view state and in fact  when you click on your added buttons, the buttons will not persist (they in fact will disappear on a post back. (unless you running that add button code each time on post-back). and your sample code only shows one button - so far then we back to hide/show the button as a better solution.   As I stated, you don't mention how many buttons you need/will optional add per row - but your code only shows one.  But, I'll post the setting for the button click to work - see my edit

Comment: I still not found the answer. Wait for other suggestion, Although I did what I want in other way.

Comment: See my edit - it shows how to add a button, and the post back. However if that page has to survive post-backs, the buttons will have problems of persistence.

Comment: BtnTest2 does not fire click event. It just refreshes the web page.

Comment: see my new Edit#2 - it does stick and work.